# file transfer problem in microwebsrv2 on esp32

Tags: esp32, micropython

programming language: micropython
board: esp32 wroom
hi, I have a zepto.min.js file on a esp32
and I use microwebsrv2 to build web server
the frond end of web site is a simple html file.
some where in this html file i use this :

```
<script src="/zepto.min.js">
```

and in micropython code I write this function to give zepto.min.js to client:

```
@WebRoute(GET,'/zepto.min.js')
def jquery_return(microWebSrv2, request):
    request.Response.SetHeader('Content-Encoding: gzip')
    request.Response.ReturnRedirect('/zepto.min.js')
```

but when I run the server and connect to it as a client my browser show this error:
[an error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duqS3.png)

can any one help me???

Comment: in your `jquery_return` you are not actually serving your 'zepto.min.js' file, you are redirecting the browser indefinitely till the browser decides that it's a circular reference. I don't know your library used, but you should look at how to serve a file.

Comment: i try many function like ReturnFile,Return,.... none of them doesnt work

Comment: what is your library for the web server?

Comment: i use microwebsrv2 : https://github.com/jczic/MicroWebSrv2

Comment: then https://github.com/jczic/MicroWebSrv2#arrow_forward-httpresponsereturnfile should help you with `httpResponse.ReturnFile(self, filename, attachmentName=None)` Do not set gzip encoding if your file is not compressed, or compress it manually before serving

Comment: I think it is about the size and type of the file I try to send.